# Issue with edittexts when using inside <include> tag

Tags: android, android-layout

Encountered a weird issue when using ViewBinding with Fragments.

fragment_one_layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/name"
        layout="@layout/form_element_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/unit"
       layout="@layout/form_element_layout" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        layout="@layout/form_element_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

form_element_layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/TextViewRegularHeading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_forms_bg"
        android:hint="@string/form_hint"
        android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

After entering values in `name.input` , `unit.input` and `quantity.input`  fields, I've navigated to `fragment_two`.

When returning from the `fragment_two` to `fragment_one`, the values in every field changed to the value of the `quantity.input`

Eg : name is "John", unit is "Kg" and quantity is "80". After navigating to fragment_two and returned, the name, unit and quantity values are changed to "80", Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving layout values, Android stores the value of an *EditText* keyed by its id. Since you are using the same id for each of your *EditTexts*, each save overwrite the previous save and the last one overwrites all of them. If you want to do a quick test of this, move the "unit" include so its the last one. You should see "Kg" for all the values after doing this. You don't see this issue for the *TextViews* since they are considered static and are simply recreated each time.

Other than reworking your layout, a way around this is to explicitly save and restore the *EditText* values yourself.

Let's take the following simple layout that has a top *EditText* and one below. The key thing to note in this layout is that both *EditTexts* have the same id.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm the top view!"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="I'm the bottom view!"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When first displayed, we see the following:

[image]

Upon rotation which forces recreation of the layout, we see this:

[image]

As you can see, the contents of the bottom *EditText* was used to fill in the top *EditText*. This is what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Right now I created a Customview and set EditText 
 `saveEnabled="false"` and managed customview's  `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRetainInstanceState`. Is this the right approach?